# Testing route from Quartz cron job in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a Camel route which looks something like this:

```
public class CamelReaderRoute extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("quartz://myjob?cron=0+0/5+*+*+*+?")
          //....(some more content)
          .routeId("MyCamelRoute");
}
```

Basically Quartz "triggers" the route every five minutes. When unit testing this route, it won't fire unless the time is precisely 00:00 or 00:05 or 00:10 and so on..

So how can I change the endpoint used in "from" so that the route fires immediately?
Here is my test class so far:

```
public class CamelRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {

@Test
public void shall_run_the_route_or_something() {
    context.getRouteDefinition("MyCamelRoute")
            .adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    //something should be done here?                       
                }
            });
```

I can see that in Camel 2.9 I can use the replaceFromWith inside my configure method, but due to dependencies and such and such, I'm stuck with Camel 2.8. Did they have any form of replaceFromWith before 2.9?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a couple of options, one would be to set the quartz "fireNow=true" option to invoke when the routes starts (though it would do that when deployed as well).  Otherwise, just break up the quartz route so the processing can be called directly...

```
from("quartz://myjob?cron=0+0/5+*+*+*+?")
    .to("direct:process");

from("direct:process")...
```

Then in your unit test...invoke the direct route, etc.

```
template.sendBody("direct:process",null);
```